# Mongoose don't create the second collection in the database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Here i am creating a second type of collection in a database using mongoose and the first collection was created in the database but the second one don't show. I have refreshed several time
but it is not showing in the database

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB",{useNewUrlParser: true}) 

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  // Creating a boiler plate how the data will be arranged inside the database
    name: String,
    rating: Number,
    review: String
});

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema) 
const fruit = new Fruit({
    name: "Apple",
    rating: 7,
    review: "5"
})
fruit.save();

// Challenge to create a people collection in the same Database

const peopleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    education: String
})

const People = mongoose.model("People", peopleSchema);

const people = new People({
    name: "Kanha",
    age: 19,
    education: "Btech"
});

people.save()  // Some problem has happened and My data has not saved inside the Database
```

Here is the picture from studio 3t

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ8BX.png)

I have tried chatGpt but it's solutions are not working,It suggested error detection but no error is showing in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the connection URL to `mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1/fruitsDB");` and is correctly inserting both collection data to mongo.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1/fruitsDB");

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // Creating a boiler plate how the data will be arranged inside the database
  name: String,
  rating: Number,
  review: String,
});

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);
const fruit = new Fruit({
  name: "Apple",
  rating: 7,
  review: "5",
});
fruit.save();

// Challenge to create a people collection in the same Database

const peopleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  education: String,
});

const People = mongoose.model("People", peopleSchema);

const people = new People({
  name: "Kanha",
  age: 19,
  education: "Btech",
});

people.save();
```

Comment: Today i run the code again and it worked. Both collection are showing in Studio 3t. Thanks for your Response.